# No feed dialogs in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests, messenger

I have a problem with the Facebook Messenger app. I have a mobile web app with two buttons, one for inviting friends (app request) and one for posting to the wall.

```
<a onClick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(1);">Invite</a> 
<a onClick="postToFeed(1);">Share</a>
```

The functions are:

```
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(selectedPizza) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Message',
        title: 'Caption',
        data: {"pizza_id" : selectedPizza, "act" : 'redirect'}
    }, requestCallback);
}

function postToFeed(selectedPizza) {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'link',
        picture: 'src',
        name: 'name',
        caption: 'caption',
        description: 'desc'
    }, requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback(response) {
}
```

I test this by clicking on a link to the app (apps.facebook.com/namespace...) in a private message. This works in the Facebook iPhone App, but not in the Facebook Messenger App for iPhone.  Nothing happens when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Are you sure Facebook Messenger App for iPhone support this ?

Comment: No I suppose it does not, but I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing something wrong or if it's just not implemented. I cant find any documentation about this. 

When trying to use the "send message" function on mobile for example, you get an error message at least.

Was looking for a definite "it's not supported" source or a workaround.